# Using \nameref{} on a \section[]{} prints the thing in [], not in {}. Why?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

So to clarify.

Its about the `\hyperref` package.

I have `\section[Introduction (Fin)]{Introduction} \label{Introduction}`

When I then go `as stated in \nameref{Introduction}...`

the output is `as stated in Introduction(Fin)...`

I would like to have the output `as stated in Introduction...`

How can I achieve that? I need the square bracket things for the tableofcontents, so I can't just delete that.

I hope its clear what I meant even without a proper MWE.

Thanks!

Comment: That's by design.

Comment: it is clear without a proper MWE, but *with* a proper MWE it would be much easier to test and look for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design. You can do it in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\toconly}{m}{\ifintoc#1\fi}
\newif\ifintoc
\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\toconly\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\intoctrue
\tableofcontents
\intocfalse

\section{Introduction\toconly{ (Fin)}}\label{intro:fin}

\section{Introduction\toconly{ (egreg)}}\label{intro:egreg}

In section~\nameref{intro:fin} we say something.

\end{document}
```

[image]